# JQUERY AJAX with Ruby on Rails - undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have a post show page, on it i am creating the ability to like and unlike a specific post. I have the following code in my posts/show.js.erb file (the part which is giving me the error):

```
$('#unlikebutton').on("click", function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'likes/<%=@firstone.id%>', (line: 32)
        method: 'delete',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
        console.log('sucess');
        $('#unlikebutton').hide();
        $('#likebutton').show();
             console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(result){
          console.log(result);
          console.log('error');
        }
    });

  });
```

However, the error I am getting is:

```
/app/views/posts/show.js.erb where line #32 raised:
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

I am confused as to why I am even getting this error.. shouldn't the ajax function only be called when the button is clicked ?

I get this error when i click a post to go to the post/show.js.erb page - which gives the following response

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/posts/81
Request Method:GET
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
```

Here is my posts controller show action:

```
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    @liked=Like.where(user_id:current_user.id, post_id: @post.id)
    @firstone=@liked.first
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end
```

My show page is being rendered via javascript as a bootstrap modal. Here is my full posts/show.js.erb page:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#modal-window").html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'posts/form') %>");


  $('#likebutton').on("click", function(){
    console.log("liked");
    $.ajax({
      url: 'likes',
      method: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {id: '<%=@post.id%>'},
      success: function(data)
      {
      console.log('sucess');
      $('#likebutton').hide();
      $('#unlikebutton').show();
           console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        console.log('error');
      }
      // error: function(result){
      //     console.log(result);
      // };

    });
  });

    $('#unlikebutton').on("click", function(){
      $.ajax({
        url: 'likes/<%=@firstone.id%>',
        method: 'delete',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data)
        {
        console.log('sucess');
        $('#unlikebutton').hide();
        $('#likebutton').show();
             console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(result){
          console.log(result);
          console.log('error');
        }
    });

  });



});
```

and here are the relevant parts of the posts/_form.html.erb page that the show.js page references:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">

  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up btn" id="likebutton" <%if !@liked.empty?%>
style="display:none" <%end%>>Like</i>

<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up btn" id="unlikebutton" <%if @liked.empty?%>style="display:none"<%end%>>Unlike</i>

</div>
</div>
```

Any ideas as to why this I am getting this error ? I have been stuck on this problem for 2 days now..and I still dont know what is going on - help please!

Comment: `@firstone` is ***nil***. Have you defined it in controller?

Comment: yes it is in my post controller show action  - see above

Comment: Try debugging it. As it stands it is nil.